# How to trigger onSelect Datalist in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-chrome

I've developed my project on Mozilla Firefox. I didn't consider other browsers. This onSelect function doesn't work on Chrome.

I have client list and want to get relevant names according to input. When user click on a client that listed, my function fills other inputs. This works very well in Firefox.

```php
<div class="form-group col-md-6">

   <label>Vorname</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="vorname" placeholder="Vorname" onSelect='selectClient(this)' list="kunden">
    <datalist id="kunden">
    <?php 
           foreach($clients as $client)
           {    
                 echo("<option id='{$client["id"]}' value='{$client["id"]}'> $client["vorname"]} {$client["nachname"]} -- {$client["address_ort"]}</option>");                                         }
     ?>                                 

    </datalist>
</div>
```

```js
function selectClient(item){

    if(!isNaN(item.value)){
    isOldClient=true;
    oldClientId=item.value;
    <?php
    echo "var clients_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
    ?>
    var client=clients_array[item.value-1];
    $("#nachname").val(client["nachname"]);
    $("#geburtsdatum").val(client["geburtsdatum"]);
    $("#vorname").val(client["vorname"]);
    $("#telefon").val(client["telefonnummer"]);
    $("#strasse").val(client["address_str"]);
    $("#hausno").val(client["address_no"]);
    $("#plz").val(client["address_plz"]);
    $("#ort").val(client["address_ort"]);
    }
    else{
        isOldClient=false;
    }
};
```

This is mozilla firefox (couldnt catch option list): https://youtu.be/rnOUudSlBv4

This is chrome : https://youtu.be/jE6DM-Gwc4I 
Hope someone will find a solution. 
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way, this will probably works on all browsers

```
 $('#vorname').on('input', function () {
     console.log('Input has been changed');
     selectClient($(this).val()); // call your function
 });
```

try this , if its selected from datalist, or type,
you can add if not empty/null condition

```
$("#vorname").on('change', function () {
    var val = this.value;
    if($('#kunden').filter(function(){
        return this;        
    }).length) {
        // if selected
        alert('selected= '+this.value);
    }else {
        // if typed
        alert('new= '+this.value)
    }
});
```

if you use this, then remove onSelect because it will trigger twice then for firefox.

Comment: I can get relevant results according to input, but i need something that understands if user clicked a client or moved on without clicking.

Comment: check it out now, if you select it  will alert you and also when you type,

Comment: Actually, it worked. When you click it is a number and goes in if state, otherwise it is a letter and nothing happens. Thanks!